# Writing files with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a variable rate of small messages coming in on RabbitMQ (5-60,000/sec) and I need to write them to files for the phase of processing.  I'd like to have each file stop at 50k lines or the last 5 minutes of data (which ever comes first).  I don't want to ACK the incoming messages until the entire file is written, flushed, and closed.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Order of messages does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP has the `multi-ack` option when sending a `basic.ack` http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.ack.multiple